# How to convert this size of array (1L,27L,2L) into (27L,2L) in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2d array and its size/shape is like (1L,27L,2L) this.I am want to change it as (27L,2L) how to do this?
[image: Please Check image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
yourArray = yourArray[0]
```